# Websocket using Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am trying to use Django channels to establish a websocket connection with the browser. The websocket fails to connect with the server:

```
[2017/01/23 23:51:50] HTTP GET / 200 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:60445]
[2017/01/23 23:51:51] WebSocket HANDSHAKING /chat/ [127.0.0.1:60451]
[2017/01/23 23:51:56] WebSocket DISCONNECT /chat/ [127.0.0.1:60451]
```

Javascript used for websocket:

```
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/chat/");
    socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        alert(e.data);
    };
    socket.onopen = function () {
        socket.send("hello world");
    };
    // Call onopen directly if socket is already open
    if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) socket.onopen();
```

settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "django_chat_server.routing.channel_routing",
    }
}
```

Routing.py

```
channel_routing = {
    # Wire up websocket channels to our consumers:
    'websocket.connect': ws_add,
    'websocket.receive': ws_message,
    'websocket.disconnect': ws_disconnect,
}
```

On loading the page, `ws_add` fires up but the connection eventually get's disconnected. Any lead on how can I debug this, or what the problem could be.

I am running the server using the command `python manage.py runserver`.

Edit:
Downgraded to `twisted` version 16.2.0. No avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also have a consumer for the websocket.connect and accept the connection, only after accepting the connection the protocol server will complete the websocket handshake

```
channel_routing = {
    "websocket.connect": consumers.ws_connect,
}
```

consumers.py

```
def ws_connect(message):
    message.reply_channel.send({
        'accept': True
})
```

see http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releases/1.0.0.html#websocket-accept-reject-flow