# Use Django Channels without views

Tags: python, django

We want to use Django Channels to use Keras with Tensorflow as model. We've tried Flask but it's not usable for production. Then we tried Javas DeepLearning4J but also got to many problems. We want to solve it with Python.

The problem is that Django is fullstack and we just need to use the websockets and execute our python code and send the results back.

There is literally no example on Google how to do this. We do this because we got an Angular frontend, Spring Boot backend and another Spring Boot Application as connector between all services. We don't need the most functionalities of Django.

It's very hard to find out what do. There is no `@socket.route` or something like this I think.

[Websocket using Django Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817871/websocket-using-django-channels) this question was maybe a bit helpful but 3 years old and probably outdated. What is the way to achieve what we need?

Comment: Really?!? How to use websockets is spelled out in the [channels documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html). What exactly are you missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use Django Channels without using any of Django in production?

This is not a problem, but you will have to have Django installed in your virtualenv nonetheless. I assume, you know how to configure Channels part of your application, si I will just describe, how you get it to work.

1. You still need project started with django: `django-admin startproject` will do the trick
2. Now that you have a working "core" project, you also need to setup your channels `routing`. I use a `routing.py` in the core projects folder (next to `settings.py`). You also need your consumers, canonically in a `consumers.py` also in the same location.
3. Then, you need to setup your channels part in the `settings.py`. For instance:

```py
# Channels
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

then you need to edit the INSTALLED APPS SECTION:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #if you dont want any of "standard" django just comment it out
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',   # <--- here you enable the channels part
]
```

4. You are ready to go! I don't know what ASGI server you are using, but you point it to the application object in your routing.py file. For instance:

```py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter,ChannelNameRouter
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers # your actual consumers for the endpoint of routes

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
    "websocket": URLRouter(
            [
                path('ws/route1/', consumers.ConsumerA),
                path('ws/route2/', consumers.ConsumerB),
                # and so on...
            ]
    ),
    "channel": ChannelNameRouter({
        "channel_name": consumers.ChannelConsumer,
        # and other channels you may have...
    })
})
```

Thats basically it. So a TLDR, you will still need to run django, but you can strip everything except channels out in settings...

Comment: Okay sorry I'm completly new to Django and also Python. I've had to clear the urlpatterns = [] and now I don't know how to connect to channel without urlPattern. With localhost:6379/ws/route1 ? or how

Comment: @CptDayDreamer Why don't you just do the tutorial I linked. It has the javascript parts needed, sets up all this configuration that was copied in this answer, but then in a usable way and explains things along the way, so you actually can understand the moving parts. Yes, it will use views, but only to render the HTML that serves the chat room page.

Comment: @Melvyn dont u think I already did that? I did but I don't understand and just can't get it running. Otherwise I wouldn't ask

Comment: Then maybe ask specific questions about  that tutorial. What exactly didn't work, cause it was completely transparent to me and got the room up and running in under 5 minutes. However, if you don't know anything about python then you're trying to run, before you can walk and should take [a step back](https://realpython.com/tutorials/basics/).

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, I looked at your question one more time and it would seem to me, that you actually don't need to use channels. The point of channels extension is (a) to enable you websocket handling within django and (b) enabling the _channel layer_ for easier communication between all connected websocket clients to the server.
If you don't need this feature (which is really nice) and just want to run some of your python code and return it, you may consider using `Tornado server`: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Comment: @LynxLike I was able to establish websockets but there seems to be a problem between Spring Boot and Django Channels. It just does not work. With Angular and Django it works fine but we need to establish the connection via our Spring Boot application. We create a StompClient in Spring Boot but we will never get in the afterConnected() method to send the request and tried literally everything